# Unable to fetch json data

Tags: android, json, locale

My server json data is like:--[]

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
        final Context context = this;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        }
    }
```

Here I can Fetch all the country name.but Rank is not coming on text-view.where is the problem??can anyone tell me????????

Comment: You are using wrong key for rank so replace this line : txt1.setText("Rank- "+jsonObject.getString("Rank"));

Comment: I have used this..But It is fetching only one rank of the country.It is not showing the Rank of the corresponding country name.

Comment: @user3553286 Have you checked my updated answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong key 'name'

```
txt1.setText("Rank- "+jsonObject.getString("name"));
```

Use this line

```
txt1.setText("Rank- "+jsonObject.getString("Rank"));
```

You have to create listener for getting item selected event of spinner.

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282880/how-to-reuse-data-from-a-jsonarray-which-got-data-in-onpostexecute/25283545#25283545) and check for code in `setOnItemClickListener()`

Add comment if you find some difficulty.

Comment: I have used this..But It is fetching only one rank of the country.It is not showing the Rank of the corresponding country name..

Comment: do you want to show rank of country on selecting country from spinner ?

Comment: Added link to answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace this code :**

```
txt1.setText("Rank- "+jsonObject.getString("name"));
```

**With this code :**

```
 txt1.setText("Rank- "+jsonObject.getString("Rank"));

Note : you have given wrong key reference to get Rank value
```

Comment: I have used this..But It is fetching only one rank of the country.

Comment: you store rank value in hashmap with name as key and selected spinner value use as hashmap key then try to show rank value from hashmap spinner value as key

Answer (score 0):

First add to your List where you are parse your data

```
nameList.add(jsonObject.getString("Rank"));
```

You are using wrong key 'name'

```
txt1.setText("Rank- "+jsonObject.getString("name"));
```

Use this line `onItemSelectedListener` of Spinner.

```
txt1.setText("Rank- "+nameList.get(position).get("Rank"));
```

Change here:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
       nameList.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
       nameList.add(jsonObject.getString("Rank"));

  }
```

Comment: I have used this..But It is fetching only one rank of the country.It is not showing the Rank of the corresponding country name.

Comment: Can You please suggest Where I have to put     
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,       int pos, long id) {}

 in my program???I cant understand

Comment: After populated your data in spinner. where you set your arraylist to your adapter. in onCreate() method.

Comment: I have added ..But still showing error in nameList and position ..Can I send you the code??

Comment: Make this  List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(); global varibale. And in your spinner onItemSelectedListener method there is one int varibale so you have to pass that instead of position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int cnt= jsonarr.length();
String country_name;
String country_rank;                    

for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++){
    country_name= jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    country_rank= jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("Rank");
}

tv.setText(country_rank.toString());
```

Hope this may help you!