# Android how to clear data from Shared Preferences?

Tags: android, eclipse

Dear Friends I want to clear my shared preference I have tried this

```
     SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
             "mypassword", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
     Editor editor = pref.edit();

     editor.putString("key_username", "");  
     editor.putString("key_password", ""); 
     editor.commit();
```

but its not working.How can I clear please help me.

Comment: Refer [this link][1] for the answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772291/how-to-save-json-from-url-and-update-the-saved-file-from-url-after-fixed-interva/24772552#24772552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the shared preference you need to add this code.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor.clear();
SharedPreferences.Editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using

```
editor.apply();
```

in place of

```
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. It will clear your SharedPreferences.

```
     SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
             "mypassword", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
     Editor editor = pref.edit();
     editor.clear(); 
     editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be used -

```
SharedPreferences settings = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences("mypassword", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Editor e = pref.edit();
e.remove("key_username");
e.remove("key_password");
e.commit();
```