# Store Value in SharedPreference across Activities

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am new in Android, and got a task to develop a small project to submit in my college, i have tried my best but now i need some help

Let me tell you first, `what i am trying to do ?`

I have two Activities, `MainActivity` and `AccountActivity`

In `MainActivity` i am using `button` to **switch** to `AccountActivity`

In `AccountActivity` i am trying to store `strBalance` value in SharedPreference but whenever i do click on `back` button and then again come to `AccountActivity` always getting `"1000"` not that value which i have stored in `SharedPreference`.

Here is the complete code of AccountActivity.java:-

```
public class AccountActivity extends Activity {

    EditText editAmount;
    int strAmount;
    Button btnPayment;
    TextView textBalance;
    int strBalance; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);      

        editAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAmt);
        btnPayment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPay);
        textBalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBalance);

        strBalance = 1000;

        textBalance.setText("Your current balance is: $ "+strBalance);      

        btnPayment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);  
                Editor editor = pref.edit();

                strAmount = Integer.parseInt(editAmount.getText().toString().trim()); // user input             

                if(strAmount>strBalance) {
                    Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, "You don't have enough balance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else 
                {
                    strBalance = strBalance - strAmount; // 1000 - 500 = 500
                    textBalance.setText("Your current balance is: $ "+strBalance);  
                    Log.v("strBalance", String.valueOf(strBalance)); // 500
                    editor.putInt("key_balance", strBalance);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Use log messages and check whether is it getting saved properly.
Print the value of strBalance, before saving and check are you getting proper value.

Comment: Please post the part of your Main Activity, where you are trying to retrieve saved data.

Comment: i am not trying to retrieve data in MainActivity, i am storing data in AccountActivity and want to show in a same one when resumes, and i have checked i am getting value in strBalance as per my requirement

Comment: Ohhoo... i found the reason, i am using strBalance = 1000; in onCreate(..) but how may i handle this @Kesh1234

Comment: Why are you initialising in onCreate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this,

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
       int any_variable = sharedPreferences.getInt("key_balance", 0);
```

Remove initialisation and do this in your onCreate and then use the new variable as you strBalance.

Answer (score 0):

-Check Both the **preference** and **key name are same or not.**

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
if (pref.getInt("key_balance", 1000) != null) {
    strBalance = pref.getInt("key_balance",1000);
} else {
    strBalance = 1000;
}
```

Instead of

```
strBalance = 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not retrieve data from `SharedPreferences`

Write your code in `onResume()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // SharedPreferences retrieval code
}
```

To know more about `SharedPreferences` check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24772552/3843374).